# js how to make 2d array matrix with for loop and continue counting numbers on next row

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to make my 2d matrix to have numbers which continue on the new row

```js
var myMatrix = [];

var row = 5;
var colom = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var toto = 1;
  myMatrix[i] = [i];
  for (var j = 0; j < colom; j++) {
    myMatrix[i][j] = [i + j];
  }

}

console.log(myMatrix);
```

I'm trying to make it print numbers like this:

> 123
>
> 456
>
> 789 and etc...

but without success:/

can someone help and also give a video or site with examples where i can learn more about that kind of stuff?

Comment: Your question shows basic gaps regarding JavaScript syntax. I suggest you read some more about arrays and integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a look at what your code is doing:

```js
const myMatrix = [];
const rows = 5;
const columns = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  myMatrix[i] = [i];
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {    
    myMatrix[i][j] = [i+j];
  }
}

console.log(myMatrix);
```

You have a typo in your `row`/`rows` variable name. Ignoring that though...

Your `myMatrix[i]` line is creating an array at `i`, which is then being set to an array with a value of `i`. Just this creates a wonky mash-up , where each "row" gets an array with it's row number as the first value, something like this:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Your inner loop then adds a value to that array at the place and adds `i+j` together, but puts that inside of an array, which isn't what you want, so you get something like this:

```
[
 [[0], [1], [2]], // i = 0
 [[1], [2], [3]], // i = 1
 [[2], [3], [4]], // i = 2
 // ... etc
]
```

Also note that you are replacing that first `[i]` anyways, so don't set it like that, just make it an empty array `[]`.

What you want is something like this:

```js
const myMatrix = [];
const rows = 5;
const columns = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  myMatrix[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {    
    myMatrix[i][j] = (i*columns)+j;
  }
}

console.log(myMatrix);
```

There were three changes to your code:

- Make the `[i]` and `[]`. It doesn't hurt anything, but `[i]` also doesn't make sense.
- Take the `i+j` part out of the array, you just want a value there.
- When you add `i`, multiply it by `columns` so it doesn't reset every time: `(i*columns)+j`

This will give you a nice output, starting with `0`. If you want it start at `1`, just add one to your value:

```js
const myMatrix = [];
const rows = 5;
const columns = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  myMatrix[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {    
    myMatrix[i][j] = (i*columns)+j+1;
  }
}

console.log(myMatrix);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use i * columns + j ...   and I have to add up to 30 chars for padding